Conditially enable code in Rust with feature flag by including dependency using git
I've tried importing a Rust library using a feature flag with git dependency. But that doesn't seem to enable the code using CFG annotations in the code but when using the regular library through crates.io it works to enable it. For example.
This doesn't work:
package_name = { git = "https://github.com/username/repo", package = "package_name", branch = "master", features = ["x"] }

This works:
package_name = { version = "0.1.0", features = ["x"] }

When going to the lib.rs file for the project I get this chunk of code disabled:
#[cfg(feature = "x")]
pub mod util;

#[cfg(feature = "y")]
pub mod util2;

It says:

Conditionally disabled code

But according to the Cargo.toml for the package:
[features]
default = ["x"]
x = []
y = []

I get this error message when trying to import:

Unresolved import: package_name::util [E0432]

So why is this happening?
(x and y is obviously just substituted from the real feature name)

@cafce25 great catch, it was a typo.

Please add a [mre] we need to know how the import target is setup.

There should be no difference how feature flags are handled whether it is a crates.io dependency or a git dependency. So something else is going on here, and thus we need more concrete info.
